# AngularFire .subscribe => console.log returning undefined after use of map or flatMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire, observable

I'm pretty new to AngularFire, Firebase, rxjs etc..

Can anyone tell me why the following returns 'undefined' from console.log?

```
    this.af.database.object('/teams/' + this.id)
        .map((data) => {
            data.teamName = Teams[data.team];
        })
        .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
```

Teams is an enum. Red = 1, Blue = 2...

I know the problem lies in the .map as if i remove it and just log x or log the enum lookup both work fine..

This works fine (and resolves red):

```
    this.af.database.object('/teams/' + this.id)
        .subscribe((x) => {
            console.log(Teams[x.team]);
        })
```

As does this (resolving a firebase observable):

```
    this.af.database.object('/teams/' + this.id)
        .subscribe((x) => {
            console.log(x);
        })
```

I've also tried flatMap on a list rather than map on an object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because returns from both `get` and `map` methods are observable, not a json.

In

```
 .map((data) => {
            data.teamName = Teams[data.team];
        })
```

you treat your `data` variable like a json but it isn't. So your variable becomes undefined. Because there's no such thing as `data.Teamname`

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data

> http.get method returns an Observable of HTTP Responses (Observable) from the RxJS library and map is one of the RxJS operators.

Comment: Thanks echonax. That makes sense.

I've saw people using toJSON?

Is there any way in which I can add to the data like that without losing the ability of using the async pipe?

I might be asking the wrong question here, my problem is that the data comes back from the database with a team value of '1', which is correct but not what I want to be displayed on screen. 

I want to do a reverse lookup on the Teams enum and display it's string.
I'm probably handling this all wrong.

Comment: @ChrissySemens You can `.map((res:Response) => res.json())` and handle the data inside your subscribe.

Comment: Eternally grateful. Thanks :D

Comment: @ChrissySemens eheh glad I could help